# How to list number of times of values occur in multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL ad convention table:

```
| id  | ad1    | ad2   | ad3    |
| ----|--------| ------| -------|
| 1   |val_1   |NULL   | NULL   |
| 2   |val_2   |val_1  | NULL   |
| 3   |val_3   |NULL   | val_3  |
```

I want to list all ads value occurrence times in column *ad1, ad2, ad3*. The query will return

```
| value   | times |
| --------| ------|
| val_1   | 2     |
| val_2   | 1     |
| val_3   | 2     |
```

What is the best way to do this(for best performance)?

Comment: Poor table design. One ad per row is recommended.

Comment: Sorry the table is *ad_convention*. ad1, ad2, ad3 is an id that reference to ad table. This is an exist database so I cannot modify the data structure.

Answer (score 3):

use `UNION ALL` in subquery

```
select t.value, count(*)
from (
   select ad1 value from ad_convention
   union all
   select ad2 value from ad_convention
   union all
   select ad3 value from ad_convention
) t
group by t.value
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of lateral joins for this:

```
select ad, count(*)
from t, lateral
     (values (ad1), (ad2), (ad3)) v(ad)
where ad is not null
group by ad;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array that is unnested:

```
select t.val, count(*)
from ads a, unnest(array[a.ad1, a.ad2, a.ad3]) t(val)
where t.val is not null
group by t.val;
```

Not sure if that is faster or slower than an `UNION ALL`